# Multiple PanResponder (draggable) elements in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Just looking for some pointers to make a second draggable element in React Native using the PanResponder.

So I've got this code in the componentWillMount function

```js
    componentWillMount = () => {
        this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
            onStartShouldSetPanResponder: this._alwaysTrue,
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: this._alwaysTrue,
            onPanResponderGrant: this._handlePanResponderGrant,
            onPanResponderMove: this._handlePanResponderMove,
            onPanResponderRelease: this._handlePanResponderEnd,
            onPanResponderTerminate: this._handlePanResponderEnd
        });
```

Now obviously all the functions such as _handlePanResponderMove are defined as well.

I then bind that to an SVG element with

```js
<Circle
   cx={this.state.x}
   cy={this.state.y}
   r="45"
   fill="white"
   {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
/>
```

Now that works fine if I just have a single SVG circle I want to make draggable. How would I go about doing this for a second circle - I'm sure there must be a better way than creating a new panResponder with all functions? Putting the same {...this._panResponder.panHandlers} in a second SVG circle obviously won't work; both circles will then move at the same time, into the same positions.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I found a temporary fix, by just creating two PanResponders. It's not ideal (not DRY), as a large amount of code is repeated. I don't have enough experience in JS to figure out how to pass correct params to these functions, so this will have to do for now.

```js
        this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: this._alwaysTrue,
            onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
                this.setState({
                    x: this._previousLeft + gestureState.dx,
                    y: this._previousTop + gestureState.dy
                });
            },
            onPanResponderEnd: (evt, gestureState) => {
                this._previousLeft += gestureState.dx;
                this._previousTop += gestureState.dy;
            },
        });

        this._secondPanResponder = PanResponder.create({
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: this._alwaysTrue,
            onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
                this.setState({
                    xS: this._previousSLeft + gestureState.dx,
                    yS: this._previousSTop + gestureState.dy
                });
            },
            onPanResponderEnd: (evt, gestureState) => {
                this._previousSLeft += gestureState.dx;
                this._previousSTop += gestureState.dy;
            },
        });
```